# To display only even numbers using map function

Tags: python, python-2.7, map-function

I am a beginner and I have to implement a code to display only even numbers from 23 to 97 using map function. I got stuck at

```
def evenfunc(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        return num
print map(evenfunc, range(23,98))
```

The output is [None, 24, None, 26, None, 28, None, 30, None, 32, None, 34, None, 36,....97]
So how to get rid of the none values?

Comment: You seem to confusing `map()` and `filter()`.

Comment: Note that `map` should really only be used if you want your resulting list to be the same length as the original list. If they're different lengths, `map` isn't the tool for the job; at least without a following `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you misunderstand what the function that's passed into `map` should do. The function passed into `map` should modify the existing input. `map` *maps* the result of the function to each element, creating a new iterable. *Not* attempt to filter it.

You need to use `filter` instead, which is made to specifically filter input based upon a condition:

```
filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(23, 98))
```

However, a list comprehension would be a better choice:

```
[x for x in range(23, 98) if x % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def evenfunc(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        return True
print filter(evenfunc, range(23,98))
```

Comment: That is not correct usage of `filter`. Although your code works, the function passed into `filter` should return true or false for each element given to it.

Comment: Should `return True`, if `num = 0` then `num%2 == 0` but you return `0` which is treated as `False`.

Comment: You could of course just simplify this to `return num%2 == 0` because while the implicit `None` works - you should be explicit.

Comment: Then you should `return False` outside of the `if` condition.